# Show list of list with checkboxes in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jsp, user-interface, jstl

I'm developing a e-commerce app in Spring MVC. I have a scenario where i have to display a list of Suppliers and for each supplier we have a list of categories in a form. 
User can choose a set of supplier with a set of categories.

> So i have to display suppliers with checkboxes and within that
>   categories with checkboxes in a form.

I am able to show supplier's name and categories with checkboxes and map it into spring modal. But how to show checkboxes with suppliers so that user can select.
A category can be mapped to any number of suppliers and user can chose any.

```
<c:forEach items="${suppliers}" var="item">
            <div class="well">
                <label><s:message text="${item.username}" /></label>
                    <div id="categories" class="well">
                        <form:checkboxes items="${item.categories}" path="categories"
                                         itemValue="id" itemLabel="descriptions[0].name"
                                        delimiter="<br/>" />
                     </div>
            </div>
</c:forEach>
```

Or is there any better way to do this?

Comment: I don't believe `form:checkboxes` is valid. You have a `for` loop iteration, as you iterate through `suppliers` you want to generate the HTML for your checkboxes. There's _kinda_ example here, but it's creating `<li>` elements, but the principle is the same: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0380__JSTL/UseJSTLtoCreateURLFromFormInput.htm

Comment: OK so it turns `<form:checkboxes>` is a thing, have a look at the example here: https://mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-checkbox-and-checkboxes-example/

Comment: Thanks, we did it with ```form:checkbox``` and ```for ```loop.

Answer (score 0):

After some struggle, we made it working code.

```
 <c:forEach var="supplier" varStatus="statusSupplier" items="${suppliers}">
                                Supplier: <c:out value="${supplier.username}" /><br>
                      <div class="checkbox-list well">
                            <form:hidden path="supplierList[${statusSupplier.index}].id"  value="${supplier.id}" />

                            <c:forEach var="category" varStatus="statusCategory" items="${supplier.categories}">
                                <form:checkbox path="supplierList[${statusSupplier.index}].categories" 
                                                     value="${category.id}"/>

                                            <c:forEach var="desc" items="${category.descriptions}">
                                                    <c:out value="${desc.name}" /><br>
                                             </c:forEach>
                            </c:forEach>     
                      </div>
</c:forEach>
```